# Is this the correct way of returning a ES6 promise in firebase cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, es6-promise

I have a cloud function similar to this:

```
exports.verifyEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => { // data contains session_id (doc id where otp is stored) and otp
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    admin.firestore().collection('verification').doc(data.session_id).get().then(doc => {
      if(data.otp === doc.data().otp){
        return resolve()
      } else {
        return reject({message: 'OTP did not match'})
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      return reject({message: err.message})
    })
  })
})
```

I read this method on a blog somewhere. Now the problem is, when I put wrong OTP on the client side, it shows error as `INTERNAL` rather than showing the error message `OTP did not match`. What would be the correct way to send the error message through?

Comment: err.message might be returning Internal

Comment: Yes, err.message on client side gives the string 'INTERNAL'.

Comment: No. Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it).

Comment: Have you tried a real `Error` instead of that object with a `message`?

Comment: @Bergi , How can I pass an error in a reject? Please give an example...

Comment: @Bergi I can't avoid the promise. I have only given a gist of the code. I have a lot more happening behind the scenes. I'm preventing the user form entering more than 10 OTPs. I'm also sending emails and stuff, depending on a lot of conditions. So I have to use a promise... Or is there an alternative for that?

Comment: @VaibhavJoshi I mean like `reject(new Error("…"))` or `reject(err)`.

Comment: @VaibhavJoshi Yes, the alternative is to use promise chaining. Also please post your actual code, unless you can reproduce the issue with the simplified code as well.

Comment: Okay, let me try with ```reject(new Error())``` else I'll post the actual code.

Comment: @Bergi , in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59392765/what-will-happen-if-i-set-the-requests-mode-to-no-cors-in-my-firebase-cloud-f this question, I have posted the code for another which is behaving in the same way. Any help?

Comment: @VaibhavJoshi Yes, that one still has the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `err.message` is returning `Internal`, then you need to change the returned error to what you want:

```
}).catch(err => {
      return reject({message: "OTP did not match"})
    })
```

Comment: The ```.catch``` is for when there's an error in retrieving the doc from the db. I can't send 'OTP did not match' if there was no document to start with. Whereas, when the document exists, and if the OTPs don't match, I have to send 'OTP did not match'.

Comment: If it is entering the catch instead of the else then you have other problems not related to the otp