# What will happen if I set the request's mode to 'no-cors' in my firebase cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions, es6-promise

This is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334202/is-this-the-correct-way-of-returning-a-es6-promise-in-firebase-cloud-functions) question. I have a firebase function which is supposed to take an OTP, validate it and then change a user's password based on whether it is correct or not (for some reason I'm not able to use firebase's inbuild password reset functionality). Following is my function:

```
exports.resetPassword = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(data.sesId && data.otp){
            admin.firestore().collection('verification').doc(data.sesId).get().then(verSnp => {
                if(verSnp.data().attempt != 'verified'){
                    var now = new Date().getTime()
                    if(verSnp.data().expiring > now){
                        if(data.email == verSnp.data().email){
                            if(verSnp.data().attempt > 0){
                                if(data.otp == verSnp.data().otp){
                                    admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
                                        admin.auth().updateUser(user.uid,{
                                            password: data.password
                                        }).then(() => {
                                            admin.firestore().collection('verification').doc(data.sesId).update({
                                                attempt: 'verified'
                                            }).then(() => {
                                                Promise.resolve()
                                            }).catch(() => {
                                                throw new Error('Error updating the database.')
                                            })
                                        }).catch(() => {
                                            throw new Error('Error updating the password. Please try again.')
                                        })
                                    }).catch(() => {
                                        throw new Error('Incorrect email. How did you get here?')
                                    })
                                } else {
                                    var redAttempt = verSnp.data().attempt - 1
                                    admin.firestore().collection('verification').doc(data.sesId).update({
                                        attempt: redAttempt
                                    }).then(() => {
                                        throw new Error(`Incorrect OTP. You have ${redAttempt} attempts remaining.`)
                                    }).catch(() => {
                                        throw new Error('Wrong OTP, try again.')
                                    })
                                }
                            } else {
                                throw new Error('Incorrect OTP. You have exhausted your attempts. Please request a new OTP.')
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new Error('Incorrect email. How did you get here?')
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('OTP is expired. Please request a new OTP.')
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Error('OTP is invalid. Please request a new OTP.')
                }
            }).catch(() => {
                throw new Error('Invalid session id. Please request the OTP through Forgot Password.')
            })
        } else {
            throw new Error('Enter OTP')
        }
    })
})
```

When I run the function, it gets executed, because I can see it in the console statements, but I'm getting following error on my client side.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/functionName' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

and when I log the response received from the function, it shows `{"code":"internal"}`.

What is the cors package? How do I solve this problem?

---

**Part 2** (not related)

Also, on lines 11 and 12 of my function, I'm using

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
  admin.auth().updateUser(user.uid, {password: data.password})
})
```

Is this correct?

---

For part 1 I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493252/firebase-hosting-and-cloud-function-cors-error) question, but it has no answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) for Callable Cloud Functions:

1. You **don't** need to encapsulate it in `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})`;
2. You **need** to return data that can be JSON encoded;
3. You **need** to manage the errors correctly, by by throwing (or returning a Promise rejected with) an instance of `functions.https.HttpsError`;
4. You **need** to correctly chain all the promises returned by the asynchronous methods.

I've tried below to re-organized your code in the lights of the points above, but since your business logic is complex I cannot test it and there might be other approaches to manage all the cases... Up to you to "polish" this first attempt! Hoping it will help.

```
exports.resetPassword = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

        if(data.sesId && data.otp){

            let dataOptCorresponds = true;

            return admin.firestore().collection('verification').doc(data.sesId).get()
            .then(verSnp => {
                if(verSnp.data().attempt != 'verified'){

                    var now = new Date().getTime()

                    if(verSnp.data().expiring > now){
                        if(data.email == verSnp.data().email){
                            if(verSnp.data().attempt > 0){
                                if(data.otp == verSnp.data().otp){
                                    return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email);
                                } else {
                                    dataOptCorresponds = false;
                                    var redAttempt = verSnp.data().attempt - 1
                                    return admin.firestore().collection('verification').doc(data.sesId).update({
                                        attempt: redAttempt
                                    })
                                }
                            } else {
                                throw new Error('Incorrect OTP. You have exhausted your attempts. Please request a new OTP.')
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new Error('Incorrect email. How did you get here?')
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('OTP is expired. Please request a new OTP.')
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Error('OTP is invalid. Please request a new OTP.')
                }
            })
            .then(user => {
                if(dataOptCorresponds) {
                    return admin.auth().updateUser(user.uid,{
                        password: data.password
                    })
                } else {
                    throw new Error(`Incorrect OTP. You have xxxx attempts remaining.`)
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                return admin.firestore().collection('verification').doc(data.sesId).update({
                    attempt: 'verified'
                })
            .then(() => {
                return {result: "success"}                      
            })          
            .catch(error => {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', error.message);

            })

        } else {

            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'Enter OTP');
        }

})
```

---

**UPDATE following Bergi's comment below:**

If you want to be able to differentiate the kind of errors returned to the front-end (in particular sending back an `invalid-argument` `HttpsError` if the OTP is incorrect, invalid or expired or if the email is incorrect) you may use a second argument in the `then()` method.

```
exports.resetPassword = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

        if(data.sesId && data.otp){

            let dataOptCorresponds = true;

            return admin.firestore().collection('verification').doc(data.sesId).get()
            .then(

                verSnp => {
                    if(verSnp.data().attempt != 'verified'){

                        var now = new Date().getTime()

                        if(verSnp.data().expiring > now){
                            if(data.email == verSnp.data().email){
                                if(verSnp.data().attempt > 0){
                                    if(data.otp == verSnp.data().otp){
                                        return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email);
                                    } else {
                                        dataOptCorresponds = false;
                                        var redAttempt = verSnp.data().attempt - 1
                                        return admin.firestore().collection('verification').doc(data.sesId).update({
                                            attempt: redAttempt
                                        })
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    throw new Error('Incorrect OTP. You have exhausted your attempts. Please request a new OTP.')
                                }
                            } else {
                                throw new Error('Incorrect email. How did you get here?')
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new Error('OTP is expired. Please request a new OTP.')
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('OTP is invalid. Please request a new OTP.')
                    }
                },

                error => {

                    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', error.message);

                }

            )
            .then(user => {
                if(dataOptCorresponds) {
                    return admin.auth().updateUser(user.uid,{
                        password: data.password
                    })
                } else {
                    throw new Error(`Incorrect OTP. You have xxxx attempts remaining.`)
                }
            })
            .then(() => {
                return admin.firestore().collection('verification').doc(data.sesId).update({
                    attempt: 'verified'
                })
            .then(() => {
                return {result: "success"}                      
            })          
            .catch(error => {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', error.message);

            })

        } else {

            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'Enter OTP');
        }

})
```

Comment: With the `.catch()` in the end, all of the `throw`n errors end up as an internal `HttpsError`. You'll need to move that up the chain or [use the second `then` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the "tip"! I've tried to adapt the answer. It would be great if you could have a look and confirm it is the correct approach! I don't see, however, how to implement a second `then()` parameter where we have `if(dataOptCorresponds)` since the error is function of the `dataOptCorresponds` value...

Comment: Ooops, forget what I was saying. I had not properly read your answer and didn't realise that you actually *wanted* all of the error messages to get wrapped in the `HttpsError`. I guess your original approach is the correct one.

Comment: Guys I really appreciate the help, but I'm not at my desk for a week due to holidays. I will respond as soon as I get the chance to try out the code.

Comment: Okay, this works, but now I have another method, where I want to update multiple documents in 3 different collections. Will chaining 3 promises work? Eg.: 
return admin.firestore().collection('collection-1').doc(docid).update({...})
.then(() => {admin.firestore().collection('collection-2').doc(docid-2).set({...})})
.then(() => {admin.firestore().collection('collection-3').doc(docid-3).delete()})
.catch(err => throw new Error(err.message))

Comment: @VaibhavJoshi Why don't you use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=1#batched-writes) to update multiple documents in 3 different collections?